# show analytic function such $f(z)={\operatorname{Log}(z+5)\over z^2+3z+2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that $f(z)=\dfrac{\operatorname{Log}(z+5)}{z^2+3z+2}$ is analytic everywhere except at the point $-1,-2$

and on the ray $\{(x,y):x\le -5,y=0\}$.

i think that separate denominator and numerator.

for each satisfying Cauchy-Riemann theorem, then $f(z)$ is also hold.

but I can't conclude the ray.

**How to prove it?**

Comment: Presumably $\log$ refers to the principal branch of the log. Think about where this is defined...

Comment: the numerator is Log(z+5). so does not exist branch(i think) since Arg(z+5) is unique

Comment: You always need a branch cut for log. Also, capital L does imply principal branch. (By the way, should there be a minus sign somewhere? Perhaps $x \le -5$?)

Comment: oh sorry man i fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\log(z)$ is analytic everywhere except on its branch cut. The principal branch cut (denote with capital L in some texts as you have here) is the negative real axis with 0, which can also be thought of as the ray $\{(x,0):x\le 0\}$.

$\log(z+5) = \log(z-(-5))$ is shifted to the left by 5, so you will need to adjust the origin of your ray accordingly.

Comment: i got it. thanks man.